# How to use colors in Motif

Tags: c++, user-interface, x11, motif

I'm new to GUI programming in C and Linux, and I'm having a hard time with it. It seems like a fairly simple/straightforward thing, but I can't find any answers googling. I want to add a background color to a widget. XmNbackground seems to be what I want to use, but I don't understand what I set it to, like a simple color blue, how do I get "blue" to set XmNbackground color to that?

Comment: Motif is dead as a doornail.  Learning it is not a good investment of your time and effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://www.motifdeveloper.com/tips/tip11.html) for an answer in the function `Pixel convert_color_name_to_pixel`, and also [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/motif-faq/part5/section-48.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource file which includes "*background: blue" or use XSetArgVal to do the same thing in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the widget in a function, you can set the widget background color resource like this, assuming the widget name is `w`:

```
XtVaSetValues(w, XmNbackground, XmRstring, "#c4c4c4", 8, NULL);
```

Where `#c4c4c3` is the hex color code for red (first two characters), green (middle two characters) and blue (last two characters).

You can also use any of the textual color names from file `rgb.txt` - where that file is located seems to be something of a moving target, but on the computer I'm using at the moment it's in `/usr/share/X11`